# dnsmasq as dns only, map mac-address to hostname for dynamic ip

Tags: dns, dhcp, dnsmasq, mac-address, lan

I'm using `dnsmasq` as a DNS server only (no dhcp), mapping Lan's hostnames to relative ip using `/etc/hosts`, but in the same Lan there's some ip assigned dynamically by a router (and I'd like to keep so, I don't want to use dnsmasq'd dhcp but I want to keep the ip dynamic).

Any way to map a MAC-address with a hostname so the DNS can respond correctly for a dynamically assigned ip?

I seen the documentation of dnsmasq and played around with `/etc/ethers` and `dhcp-host=` but the former is only for MAC->ip (not hostname) and the latter only if dhcp is enabled, so far found nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved, see <strike>[poor-mans-device-discovery-dns](http://myatus.com/p/poor-mans-device-discovery-dns/)</strike> [new link](https://medium.com/myatus/poor-mans-device-discovery-dns-492a95ea8c8b)

Use dnsmasq's option `addn-hosts=/etc/dyn.hosts` to read an additional `hosts` file, which is generated periodically using the command `arp-scan` (and `cron` or whatever).

Comment: Link has changed, updated link is https://medium.com/myatus/poor-mans-device-discovery-dns-492a95ea8c8b